# Decrypt and copy blob to other blob storage account?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net, azure-keyvault

I'm using [this approach](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-encrypt-decrypt-blobs-key-vault/) to encrypt files and store them in Azure block blobs. I would like to copy the encrypted blob to another blob storage account and decrypt it in the process. I know it's possible to do a "copy blob" operation which runs entirely inside Azure asynchronously and doesn't download the blob contents through my local computer in transit. I believe this is accomplished through the `CloudBlockBlob.StartCopy` method. But is it possible to do that with an encrypted file and decrypt it in transit to the other storage account?

Following that link above, my code looks like the following. `blob.OpenRead` works but `blob2.StartCopy` doesn't work.

```cs
BlobEncryptionPolicy policy = new BlobEncryptionPolicy(null, cloudResolver);
BlobRequestOptions options = new BlobRequestOptions() { EncryptionPolicy = policy };
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("MyFile.txt");
//var blobStream = blob.OpenRead(null, options); //this works

CloudBlockBlob blob2 = container2.GetBlockBlobReference("MyFile2.txt");
blob2.StartCopy(blob, null, null, options, null); //this fails with: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

Comment: Which nuget package and version are you using for storage account management?

Comment: @juvchan 6.1 Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage DLL

Comment: just to be sure, your storage account is created in Class mode or Resource Manager mode? Seems like the earlier by the nuget you're using.

Comment: @juvchan Classic. Does it matter for this?

Comment: I would say Yes, it's always better to be very specific to help to reproduce and troubleshoot the issue. If I have this doubt, some others could have too.

Comment: @juvchan - I don't think it would matter if the storage account is created in classic/ARM way in this particular scenario. That impacts how the storage account themselves are managed (from Service Management/ARM API perspective). Management of data inside the storage account remains the same. In both cases, it would make use of account name/key for data management.

Comment: Greg - Are you copying across storage accounts? Since you used `container` variable for both source and target blob, I got confused. Also please let us know the source container's ACL. Is it `Private`?

Comment: @GauravMantri yes from storage account A to B. Sorry. Will fix my cleaned up code sample. Both containers are private.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thanks very much for the info

Comment: No, Classic/RM wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is that encryption is done in the storage client library so if you do a copy blob to a new storage account it will still be encrypted.

The reason your code is failing is because the source blob is in a `Private` container. For cross-account copy to work, the source blob should be publicly accessible. Within same storage account, you can copy a blob from a private container. AFAIK, the error has nothing to do with encryption.

What you could do is create a SAS URL on the source blob and then use the following override of [`StartCopy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.startcopy.aspx) method:

```
public string StartCopy(
    Uri source,
    AccessCondition sourceAccessCondition = null,
    AccessCondition destAccessCondition = null,
    BlobRequestOptions options = null,
    OperationContext operationContext = null
)
```

Here's the sample code to do so:

```
    private static void StartCopyAcrossAccount()
    {
        var sourceAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("source-account-name", "source-account-key"), true);
        var sourceContainer = sourceAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference("source-container");
        var sourceBlob = sourceContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("blob-name");
        var sourceBlobSas = sourceBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
            {
                SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
                Permissions = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read
            });
        var sourceBlobSasUrl = sourceBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + sourceBlobSas;

        var targetAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("target-account-name", "target-account-key"), true);
        var targetContainer = targetAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference("target-container");
        var targetBlob = targetContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("blob-name");

        var copyId = targetBlob.StartCopy(new Uri(sourceBlobSasUrl), null, null);
    }
```

Comment: Gaurav, that's a fantastic answer and I learned a lot from it about copy blob. Thanks! I've edited the answer to clarify that the encrypted file stays encrypted. With your code, the CopyBlob is succeeding but the file is encrypted in the destination container. I believe that's because copy blob just dups the blob without decrypting it in transit. Feel free to review my edit to your answer, but I will accept it now.

Comment: `I believe that's because copy blob just dups the blob without decrypting it in transit.` - That's correct. A copy blob operation simply copies the bytes from source to target. Please note that a copy blob operation can be used not only copies Azure Blobs in the same/across storage account but also can be used to copy any publicly accessible file (say a file hosted in Amazon S3 for example) to blob storage as well. Thus it doesn't know (care) about the blob.

Comment: wow! I didn't know that. Thought it was only for blob-to-blob copy. If you haven't blogged about copying from S3 without the file passing through your .NET client machine that would be a good post.

Comment: Just a note: When you copy a blob, you can replace the metadata at the same time. If the source blob is encrypted, don't do this, because some of the encryption info is stored in the blob metadata. You can retrieve the metadata and add to it or modify specific values, but be careful that you don't just replace all of it. If you lose the encryption info, you will never be able to decrypt that blob.